# Extract longest json from column

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
ID    Message
A    {"message":"something happened"}
B    {"message":"hello"}
C    {"message":"love you"}
```

How could I extract longest value from column message(value with highest amount of keys in json).
So, desired result is to extract {"message":"something happened"}. Message column consists of jsons

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
subset(df, nchar(Message)==max(nchar(Message)))
```

Comment: its not highest number of keys in json, its amount of characters

Comment: @french_fries `nchar` gets the number of characters